# It is possible to pass a Class<> object in Android Layout XML?

Tags: android, xml, view

I am building a custom View that requires as one of its Attributes a Class<> object to an entity. While I made it work programmatically by adding a Setter for it, I was wondering if there is any good way to allow adding it to the XML for the layout as well?

There does not appear to be a format option for a styleable with type "class". I could use a String, but then I'd have to gamble that the value is actually a valid Class and I'd lose type hinting, so it'd not be ideal.

Is there any good way to make this work, or should I just stick with setting it programmatically?

Answer (score 6):

### Method 1 (With warnings):

**Generic CustomView:**

```
public class CustomView<T> extends View {

    private List<T> typedList = new ArrayList<T>();
    
    public CustomView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
    
    public void addTypedValue(T object){
        typedList.add(object);
    }
    
    public T getTypedValue(int position){
        return typedList.get(position);
    }
}
```

**Activity:**

```
//unsafe cast!
CustomView<String> customViewGeneric = (CustomView<String>) findViewById(R.id.customView);  
customViewGeneric.addTypedValue("Test");
String test = customViewGeneric.getTypedValue(0);
```

**XML:**

```
<org.neotech.test.CustomView
    android:id="@+id/customView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

---

### Method 2 (No warnings, safe!):

This method uses a generic CustomView. And for each type that will be used in xml you will need to create a specific class.

I have added an example implementation:

**Generic CustomView:** (Do not inflate this one in xml):

```
public class CustomView<T> extends View {

    private List<T> typedList = new ArrayList<T>();
    
    public CustomView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
    
    public void addTypedValue(T object){
        typedList.add(object);
    }
    
    public T getTypedValue(int position){
        return typedList.get(position);
    }
}
```

**XML inflatable view for the String type:**

```
public class CustomViewString extends CustomView<String> {
    
    //ADD Constructors!
    
}
```

**XML inflatable view for the Integer type:**

```
public class CustomViewInteger extends CustomView<Integer> {
    
    //ADD Constructors!
    
}
```

**Activity:**

```
CustomViewString customViewString = (CustomViewString) findViewById(R.id.customViewString);
CustomView<String> customViewGeneric = customViewString;
```

**XML:**

```
<org.neotech.test.CustomViewString
    android:id="@+id/customViewString"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<org.neotech.test.CustomViewInteger
    android:id="@+id/customViewInteger"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```